# .text, .bss, .data sections are not showed in kernel module

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I have the following kernel module and Makefile for Linux running on Beaglebone board.

```c
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>

s32 gval = 200;
static s32 __init test_init(void)
{
    pr_info("%s done : gval:%d\n", __FUNCTION__, gval);
    return 0;
}
static void __exit test_deinit(void)
{
    pr_info("%s done : gval:%d\n", __FUNCTION__, gval);
}
module_init(test_init);
module_exit(test_deinit);
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

```make
export ARCH=arm
export CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabi-
BBB_KERNEL_SRC=kernel_source_path
EXTRA_CFLAGS += -g -DDEBUG
obj-m += test_km.o
test_km-objs := kmodule.o
all:
    make -C $(BBB_KERNEL_SRC) M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
    make -C $(BBB_KERNEL_SRC) M=$(PWD) clean
```

The module builds fine and *test_km.ko* file is generated, when the *test_km.ko* file is `insmod`, the */sys/modules/test_km/sections* shows the following.

```
.ARM.exidx.exit.text
.ARM.exidx.init.text
.exit.text
.gnu.linkonce.this_module
.init.plt
.init.text
.note.Linux
.note.gnu.build-id
.plt
.rodata
.rodata.str1.4
.strtab
.symtab
```

Why the *.text, .data, .bss* sections not present for this kernel module.

I have downloaded the kernel source from *https://github.com/beagleboard*

Linux kernel version : 5.10.120

Comment: What kernel version is this? /sys/modules/${module}/sections seems to be a directory on all the systems I have looked at.

Comment: I have edited the post to add the Linux kernel version. Yes the memory sections mentioned in post are output of "ls -la /sys/modules/$(module)/sections/"

Answer (score 1):

> Why the .text, .data, .bss sections not present for this kernel module?

TL;DR : **Because you haven't coded any.**

The macros, `module_init()` and `module_exit()` place those functions in the *init* and *exit* sections.

`s32 gval = 200;` is only references by the init and exit code and the tools have deduced that just the constant 200 can be used.

You need to add non-init and non-exit code and then the tools will start to put things in .text, .data and .bss.